# Creating database tables not working. Microsoft Access

Tags: php, database, ms-access

At the moment I'm making a forum-like website.
Each time a user is making a new forum thread, I want it to also create a new table in my database, which I cant seem to achieve.
I've tried a couple of different ways, but simply cant seem to get it to work.
Before posting any of my code, please let me know if any more code is needed, in order for you to understand my question.

When running the function I get this error:

```
Caught exception: Source: Microsoft JET Database Engine
Description: Syntax error in field definition. CREATE TABLE MovingThreadTable1 (text text);
Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at D:\wwwWEB\www\2014-2015\WEB14_13\dbtools.php:39) in D:\wwwWEB\www\2014-2015\WEB14_13\createMovingThread.php on line 18
```

Function that creates the table:

```
function createForumMovingThreadsTable($movingThreadTableName){
    $sql = "CREATE TABLE MovingThreadTable1 (text text);";
    sql($sql);
}
```

sql function:

```
function sql($query){
    $conn = new COM ("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
    //$connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=D:\\wwwWEB\\www\\2014-2015\\WEB14_49\\test\\userdb.mdb";
    $root = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"];
    $connStr = "PROVIDER=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=$root\\2014-2015\\WEB14_13\\db\\userdb.mdb";

    $conn->open($connStr);
    try
    {
        $rs = $conn->execute($query);

        # Assosiative array
        $assoc_array = array();

        # Number
        $index = 0;

        # The below code will create an array (depending on the fields of the database table of course):
        # Click to see the array created by the code below
        if ($rs->State) {
            # Iterate through our result
            while (!$rs->EOF) {

                for ($x = 0; $x < $rs->Fields->Count; $x++) {
                    $assoc_array[$index][$rs->Fields[$x]->Name] = $rs->Fields[$x]->Value;
                }
                # Move cursor to next row in recordset
                $rs->MoveNext();
                $index++;
            }
        }

        $conn->Close();
        return $assoc_array;
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $conn->Close();
        echo 'Caught exception: ',  $e->getMessage(), "\n";
        echo $query;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Tell me if more information is needed.

Comment: By the way, this is not an optimal strategy. Threads could virtually be infinite, hence your code is forcing an infinite database restructuring (i.e., table creation). Also, the table name will exist on next run of code. Plus, this table maintains no index id such as `userid` for referencing. Why not maintain one table, `MovingThreads` and run inserts/updates/deletes accordingly?

Answer (score 0):

Text is a reserved word in MS Access Jet/ACE Engine. Consider bracketing the field name or entirely changing the field name.

```
CREATE TABLE MovingThreadTable1 ([text] text);
```